# IE9 Caching Text Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, web-applications

I have a ASP.NET web application that creates a text file report and then redirects to the file.

```
Response.Redirect(strFileName);
```

The problem is it seems that IE9 does something different in regards to caching.  If I generate two reports, IE9 always displays the first one generated.  I have to do a CTRL+F5 to see the updated file.  This problem doesn't occur on any other browser.

I have tried adding commands to change the caching to no avail.

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

I would like to preserve the functionality of generating a text file for recording purposes. One solution is to dump all the information from the text file onto the page and avoid the `Response.Redirect`, but this seems like more of a hack than a real fix.  Is there any way to force IE to reload the text file?

Comment: Have you tried `Response.Redirect(strFileName + "?q=" + DateTime.Now().ToString())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like version.

```
string strFileName = GetReportUrl();
string version = GetCurrentReportVersion(); // - or to use DateTime.Now.ToString();
string url = string.Format("{0}?v={1}", strFileName, version);

Response.Redirect(url);
```

In that case browsers will always use last report version.

Answer (score 0):

@Oleksandr's answer should work and is easy to implement.

An alternative would be to redirect to another .net page which contains the `Response.Cache` settings you mention. You would write the contents of your text file into this new page.

The problem with your approach is that your `Response.Cache` settings apply to the page you're in and not to the page you're redirecting to.